# Error message from embedded QuickSight dashboard - what is the meaining of DatasetRulesUserDenied?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I'm embedding a QuickSight dashboard on a web page and when it loads, I get a message saying:

> There is an issue with your data set rules.  Contact your data set owner for asssistance.  Error code: DatasetRulesUserDenied

I can't find any information about this message.  Has anyone run into this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this happen when the underlying data is being secured by row-level-security but the row-level-security table does not contain an entry for the current user's `UserName`.

If this sounds like your case, ensure your RLS is properly hooked up and ensure that your username is correct. When you're embedding, it's important to note that the user-name can be prefixed with the embedding role (e.g. `my_embedding_role/some_user` rather than just `some_user`).

Comment: Thanks for adding the bit about roles for embedding QuickSight!

Comment: user will also required to logout and login again after any changes on `row-level-security`